# How to find the general solution for this ODE?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

I'm really stuck on how to go about solving the following first order ODE; I've got little idea on how to approach it, and I'd really appreciate if someone could give me some hints and/or working for a solution so I can have a reference point on how to approach these sorts of problems.

The following is one of many ODE's I've gotten off a problem set I found in a textbook at a library:

$$y' = xe^{-\sin(x)} - y\cos(x)$$

Can anyone help?

Comment: have you solved $$y'(x)+y(x)\cos(x)=0$$?

Comment: So in general we should always begin these by equating to 0 and solving for y?

Comment: yes indeed, you can surely find something in the internet

Comment: it is $$y(x)=C_1e^{-\sin(x)}$$

Comment: Consult your textbook. This is a "first-order linear differential equation".  Your textbook probably has formulas for solving this immediately, without going through the "homogeneous, then particular solution" method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always like to think of these type of ODE's in terms of the product rule.
\begin{equation}x=y'e^{\sin(x)}+y\cos(x)e^{\sin(x)}=\left(ye^{\sin(x)}\right)'
\end{equation}
So integrating both sides and dividing by $e^{\sin(x)}$ yields\begin{equation}y=e^{-\sin(x)}\left(\frac{1}{2}x^2+c\right).
\end{equation}

Answer (score 3):

This kind of ODE should be solved as follows:

1. Solve the corresponding **homogeneous** equation.

In your case it is $y'+y\cos(x)=0$ which has solution $y=c\cdot e^{-\sin(x)}$.

2. **Consider constant** in previous solution **as a function of variable $x$** and substitute it in original equation.

So, we have $y(x)=c(x)\cdot e^{-\sin(x)}$ and should substitute it into $y'+y\cos(x) = xe^{-\sin(x)}$.

This leads us to general solution in the form of $y(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^2e^{-\sin(x)}+ce^{-\sin(x)}$.

Answer (score 1):

The particular solution is
$$y=\frac{1}{2}x^2 e^{-\sin x}$$

Then solve for the homogeneous solution.

Can you take it from here?